# Using a case statement in data validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have two tables, t1 and t2, connected with ID field
I need to test that-

```
1. t1.ROE is 1 when t2.Currency1 = t2.Currency2
2. t1.ROE is equal to t2.ROE, otherwise
```

Please help me generate a script for it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please read [ask]. Hint: show us whhat you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `or` operator like this:

```
select *
from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        and ((t1.ROE = 1 and t2.Currency1 = t2.Currency2) or(t1.ROE <> 1 and t1.ROE = t2.ROE))
```